# Calculating Electric fields of a line charge: where does this term come from?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge

The electric field at a point $P$ from a line of charge q is defined as the following:

$$dE_x=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\rho dx}{r^2}\frac{x}{r}$$
$$dE_y=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\rho dx}{r^2}\frac{y}{r}$$

where $r$ is the distance from $dx$ to point $P$.

Where does the term $\frac xr$ come from in the equation for the $x$ component of the $E$ field?

Comment: $\cos \theta = \text{adj}/\text{hyp} = x / r$ and $\sin\theta = y /r$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer might appear a bit needlessly complicated but the process generalises nicely to more complicated questions you may encounter. If anything is unclear here just let me know. If you're already familiar with the mechanics of displacement vectors you can skip to the end.

I considered the following setup to solve this problem. I've only shown a segment of the line of charge, where I've said the charge $q = \rho{dx}$, where $\rho$ is the charge density per unit length.

- $\vec{r}_P$ is the displacement vector from the origin to the point P.
- $\vec{r}_q$ is the displacement vector from the origin to the charge q.
- $\hat{u}$ is the unit vector pointing from the charge q to the point P. This is the direction the electric field points in.

[image: Overview of problem setup]

The electric field at $\vec{r}_P$ due to the charge q at $\vec{r}_q$ is the following:
$$ d\vec{E} = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{\rho dx}{|\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_q|^2}\hat{u}$$

One possible source of confusion here can be the the expression $|\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_q|^2$. This expression in fact first gives us the displacement vector pointing from q to P and then we find its magnitude and square it. This will give us exactly the squared distance between q and P. If you're unsure about why this works consider the following diagram showing vector addition:

[image: Vector Addition]

So just to reiterate, $\vec{r}_q + \vec{r}_{qP} = \vec{r}_P$, so then we can rearrange this and find $\vec{r}_{qP} = \vec{r}_{P} - \vec{r}_q$, exactly as we stated above.

The last remaining piece of the puzzle is the unit vector $\hat{u}$ which will exactly explain where your $\frac{x}{r}$ and $\frac{y}{r}$ come from. The unit vector is defined as follows, where we normalise it to give us a magnitude of 1.

$$ \hat{u} = \frac{\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_q}{|\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_q|}$$

If we now write down $\vec{r}_P$ and $\vec{r}_q$ in terms of the $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ basis vectors, where y and x are the magnitudes of the respective displacement vectors:

$$ \vec{r}_P = y\hat{j}$$
$$ \vec{r}_q = x\hat{i}$$

Finally we see:

$$ \hat{u} = \frac{\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_q}{|\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_q|} = \frac{y\hat{j} - x\hat{i}}{|\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_q|}$$

Our electric field is now written as:

$$ d\vec{E} = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{\rho dx}{|\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_q|^2}\frac{y\hat{j} - x\hat{i}}{|\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_q|}$$

If you look at the x and y components of the electric field (coefficients of $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ respectively):

$$ dE_x = -\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{\rho dx}{|\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_q|^2}\frac{x}{|\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_q|}$$

$$ dE_y = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{\rho dx}{|\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_q|^2}\frac{y}{|\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_q|}$$

This is exactly the decomposition of the electric field at point P into its x and y components, notice I've dropped the vector notation for the electric field now that we're considering each component separately.

This matches what you provided in your question (I've just used some extra vector notation but if you define $r = |\vec{r}_P - \vec{r}_q|$ then we have a match). My expression for the x component of the electric field is negative, however this will be positive if you consider the left hand plane (x < 0). So in fact integration over the whole line charge will result in a net zero x component for the electric field as they cancel.